# FIRST_VALUE working correctly but LAST_VALUE not giving desired results

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

In the following query:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dog_guid ORDER BY created_at ASC) AS test_number,
    LAG(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY dog_guid ORDER BY created_at ASC) AS previous_test_date,
    CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, LAG(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY dog_guid ORDER BY created_at ASC), created_at)/(60*60*24) AS FLOAT) AS date_diff_days,
    CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, LAG(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY dog_guid ORDER BY created_at ASC), created_at)/(60) AS FLOAT) AS date_diff_mins,
    FIRST_VALUE(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY dog_guid ORDER BY created_at ASC) AS first_test_date,
    LAST_VALUE(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY dog_guid ORDER BY created_at ASC) AS last_test_date
FROM    
    complete_tests c
WHERE
    dog_guid IS NOT NULL
```

The FIRST_VALUE() function is working accurately but the LAST_VALUE() is just giving the date of that column. Why is that?

Comment: Because you forgot your range in `LAST_VALUE`. It's working exactly as documented (and correctly). See the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-using-first_value-and-last_value-in-a-computed-expression) in the documentation that explains this exact behaviour.

Comment: Because the default range is `BETWEEN RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, which works fine for the first value but not the last. You can override this range explicitly, but a simpler approach is just to do a `FIRST_VALUE()` over the same order but `DESC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by [@JeroenMostert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68130225/first-value-working-correctly-but-last-value-not-giving-desired-results#comment120414865_68130225), when you add an `ORDER BY` to an `OVER` clause (of an analytical function which takes `ROWS/RANGE`), **the default window is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`**, therefore the last value in the window is always the current row.

What you want is `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`, so you need to add that explicitly. Unintuitive, but that is how it is.

You should also add this to `FIRST_VALUE` for performance reasons.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dog_guid ORDER BY created_at ASC) AS test_number,
    LAG(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY dog_guid ORDER BY created_at ASC) AS previous_test_date,
    CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, LAG(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY dog_guid ORDER BY created_at ASC), created_at)/(60*60*24) AS FLOAT) AS date_diff_days,
    CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, LAG(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY dog_guid ORDER BY created_at ASC), created_at)/(60) AS FLOAT) AS date_diff_mins,
    FIRST_VALUE(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY dog_guid ORDER BY created_at ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS first_test_date,
    LAST_VALUE(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY dog_guid ORDER BY created_at ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS last_test_date
FROM    
    complete_tests c
WHERE
    dog_guid IS NOT NULL
```

---

Strictly speaking, you could change it to `FIRST_VALUE` and `DESC`, but this is going to bad for performance, firstly because it will need a second sort, and secondly because the window is still `RANGE` which requires an on-disk worktable.